# Use p:AjaxStatus for different Component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two `<p:inputText/>` that i want use with the `<p:ajaxStatus/>` compeonent. When i run my page  `<p:ajaxStatus/>` runs for both input texts. I want to display  separate `<p:ajaxStatus/>` for each input text . Could you please see my code and solve this problem?

```
 <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:inputText id="companynameInputText" value="#{AccountInfo.companyName}"  requiredMessage="#{signup_msg.requiredorganization}" required="true" style="width: 100%">
                            <f:validator validatorId="organizationNameUniqueValidator" />
                            <p:ajax  update="companyNameMessage"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:watermark for="companynameInputText" value="#{signup_msg.companyname}" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </td>
                <td>  
                    <p:ajaxStatus >              
                        <f:facet  name="start">
                            <p:graphicImage   value="resources/img/loading.gif"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="complete">
                            <h:outputText value="" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:ajaxStatus>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p:inputText value="#{AccountInfo.position}" id="positionInputText" requiredMessage="#{signup_msg.requiredposition}" required="true" style="width: 100%"/>
                    <p:watermark for="positionInputText" value="#{signup_msg.position}" />
                </td>
                <td/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:inputText  id="userNameInputText" value="#{AccountInfo.bizBizNetId}"  requiredMessage="#{signup_msg.reqiredpassword}" required="true" style="width: 100%">
                            <f:validator validatorId="UserNameValidator"/>
                            <p:ajax  update="userNameMessage"/>

                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:watermark for="userNameInputText" value="#{signup_msg.mobileemail}" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p:ajaxStatus>              
                        <f:facet name="start">
                            <p:graphicImage value="resources/img/loading.gif"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="complete">
                            <h:outputText value="" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:ajaxStatus>
                </td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
```

Comment: What is supposed to trigger the ajaxStatus? If you share that here, I'll be able to add a sample usage of `<p:blockUi/>` to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the primefaces website about `<p:ajaxStatus/>`

> Ajax Status is a **global** indicator to inform users about the ajax interactions.

The important part is the **global**, meaning only one `<p:ajaxStatus/>` is available per page and that one will handle all components that carry out any ajax processing on that one page.

Use [BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf) instead if you want individual ajax status indicators per component

Comment: Dear kolossus
thnx for ans. my question. it,s working now :)
but the second problem happend. when my image run, it is showing in center of page, but i want it,s show near my InputText.
is there any way to move my picture to show near my InputText??
should i use "Style" for my "<p:graphicImage>" ?

Comment: @M.rEzAmOjaLlaL you're welcome. You could experiment with the style of the `<p:graphicImage/>`, or have the blockUi block an empty component(`<h:panelGrid/>` or smth) placed next to your inputText. Ideally, blockui just blocks a component so you really shouldn't have to do the positioning yourself